# Using javascript code to disable backspace in chrome, disables Silverlight input fields

Tags: javascript, silverlight

I don't think that this is possible, but I figure I should at least ask:

I'm running a silverlight app, yet I have this simple javascript code to disable the backspace key to prevent going back a page in the browsers:

```
function suppressBackspace(evt) {
        evt = evt || window.event;
        var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

        if (evt.keyCode == 8 && !/input|textarea/i.test(target.nodeName)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    document.onkeydown = suppressBackspace;
    document.onkeypress = suppressBackspace;
```

In IE and Firefox, it works as intended in Silverlight; but in Chrome, the backspace button is completely disabled when using input fields.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Odd, I can't reproduce this (Chrome 36 on Windows 8.1).  Does it help if you replace `/input|textarea/i` with `/input|textarea|object/i`?

Comment: I tried adding object - while it does work, the behavior is just like it would be without the javascript code. And I am testing on Win 8 with Chrome 36.